# How to check dual boot in my ubuntu

Tags: uninstall

How can I check if it is dual boot os in my system or not.When I restart my system, it doesn't shows any option regarding windows OS. If there is no windows, how can I uninstall ubuntu from my system ? please help !!!

Comment: if you had pre-installed windows and you installed Ubuntu then you have a dual boot system.

Comment: Open `gparted`. What does it show? I'm not sure of a 100% definitive way to tell if Windows is installed other than poking around and searching for it.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to not know how to configure GRUB to boot from windows. You need os-prober then you have to reconfigure GRUB.

```
sudo apt-get install os-prober
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

After that second command, you should find something that says that a Windows medium has been found or something.